# How to listen for an event on non-exsitent object backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have the following html:

```
<input type="text" name="location" id="location-view" class="location-field loc-update-geo js-typeahead-input" placeholder="City / State / Zip" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="hidden" name="zip" id="zip" data-geo-type="zip" />
<input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" data-geo-type="lat" />
<input type="hidden" name="lng" id="lng" data-geo-type="lng" />
<ul class="typeahead__results fad js-typeahead-results"/>
//here is li with class of .js-typeahead-selection 
//this populates when a user types in the field
```

I am using backbone on the view for the form and am trying to capture a mouseup event on the input (it has type ahead). Since the lis do not exist yet I can access them in the console by using (it works):

```
$('.typeahead__results')
.on('mouseup', '.js-typeahead-selection', function(){alert('type') });
```

but I am not quite sure how to implement inside my backbone code. I have this:

```
initialize : function () {
    var that = this;
    $('.typeahead__results')
.on('mouseup', '.js-typeahead-selection', function(){that.getCoordinates();});
```

but it is not working for me and I'm not quite sure how to use listenTo in this context and still get the geocoding to occur and populate the hidden fields.

I'm not trying to populate the input, just have the click/selection fire off a lat/lng lookup to populate hidden fields WHEN a user clicks or selects one of the typeahead suggestions. The function is getCoordinates inside a backbone view. Problem is that the li with the class '.js-typeahead-selection' doesn't exist until a user types something. Thats why Im using 'on' to get the parent. I'm trying to figure out how to reference properly with listenTo or reference properly with 'on'.

Comment: This is basic html (name) which means the 'id' and 'name' have to match for the DOM to have a valid path to the object. If this was a button the same rules would apply, except you can label the button with the 'value' attribute.

Answer (score 2):

[`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) is used to listen to events triggered by backbone objects such as models collections etc, not DOM events. To listen to DOM events emitted by child elements of a view, you define an [**events hash**](http://backbonejs.org/#View-events) on the view.

For example:

```js
Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },
  events: {
    'mouseup .typeahead__results': 'getCoordinates'
  },
  render: function() {
    /* here you add .typeahead__results and stuff to this view instance, then initialize typeahead functionality and so on*/
  },
  getCoordinates: function() {
    // whatever
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it helps. I did try an event as suggested, but it's not getting the click on the <li class=".js-typeahead-selection">foo</li> since the way the backend guys did it has an array of about 50 cities output to the page that gets updated occasionally from a db. Like so: window.cityNames = new Array(); window.cityNames.push("Alameda");There might be a way for me to grab that, but it is also working in concert with a typeahead script. I realise this is not optimal, but the path cant be changed. This file works on several forms with location fields

Comment: @MrBrimm I didn't get what exactly is your issue, but you should have `<li class="js-typeahead-selection">foo</li>` without the period instead of `<li class=".js-typeahead-selection">foo</li>`. Backbone view uses event delegation so however you populate the select options, if it matches the selector and it's inside the view element, the handler will work.

Comment: @T J copy paste fail is all.